# pip 1.5.6 upgrade behind proxy not working

Tags: python, proxy, debian, pip

I need to upgrade pip, and I'm using:

`# python get-pip.py --proxy=[user:Password@]10.20.30.1:8082`

but I get:

`etrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa5a1e84550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))': /simple/pip/`

The proxy is working fine.

Comment: The version 1 of pip has some troubles with proxies. You should try to set the `https_proxy` environment variable, for example by adding it before the pip call: `https_proxy="http://passwd:user@proxy:port" pip install -U pip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of proxy is it? If it is an NTLM proxy you need to use [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)

and then configure it with your proxy details.
Then set your --proxy for PIP to 127.0.0.1:3128

Comment: I tried to use CNTLM, but no luck. 
If I export the proxy like this:

`export http_proxy=http://user:Password@10.20.30.1:8082/`

wget google.com is working.

I setup cntlm with same credentials, added:

`http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5865/
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:5865/`

to /etc/environment 

but is not working.

Comment: I manage to install pip 8.1.2 from sources, but now I get:

`~# pip --proxy http://user:Password@10.20.30.1:8082 install django==1.7.11  
Collecting django==1.7.11
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)",) - skipping  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==1.7.11 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django==1.7.11`

Comment: Once you have CNTLM working, pip should point to your local CNTLM proxy and not the actual proxy. CNTLM will then route your request through the proxy for you. If you have the environmental variables set up (HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY) then you should be able to pip install without specifying --proxy in the command. edit: Now that you have the new version of pip installed, have you removed the environmental variables?

Comment: Something's strage, most probably I'm doing something wrong. With same credentials that are working from cli with `export http_proxy` , CNTLM is not working, I get: `Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required

Username/Password Authentication Failed.
`
If I remove the environmental variables, I get `~$ wget google.com
--2016-11-24 21:16:42--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘google.com’
`

Comment: Do you know what type of proxy it is?

Comment: Yes, it's a NTLM.

Comment: I have found that I need to restart CNTLM once I have updated my details, otherwise it doesn't work. Possibly configure your CNTLM using your username and password and your actual proxy details, set the HTTP_PROXY=127.0.0.1:3128 and restart.

Comment: Looks like there is a network admin who is playing with filters, now is working. Thanks